# code does not work in sublime text when using function with "return" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext4

I'm new to python programming, and as a beginner I want to start by using a code editor,
I choose sublime text 4 but I face this problem,
So help me please !
This is the code :

```
def return_string(your_string):
    if len(your_string) >= 4:
        new_string = your_string[0:2] + your_string[-2:]
        return new_string
    elif len(your_string) == 2:
        new_string = your_string * 2
        return new_string
    elif len(your_string) < 2:
        new_string = ""
        return new_string

return_string("welcome")**
```

the expected output is `"weme"` but I get nothing in sublime text output (when I click <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>).

When I change `return` to `print` the code is executed properly.

[image: problem with]
[image: no problem with]

By the way the code above works in **vscode** without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't print outside the REPL normally, unless you explicitly tell it to. Add a call to `print` on your last line:

```
print(return_string('welcome'))
```

This is why adding an explicit `print` in your function works.

You can store the value into a variable first if you want to use it elsewhere:

```
result = return_string('welcome')
print(result)
```

Comment: Please I need some clarification, why the code is executed properly in vscode ide using return statement and just calling the function without print it just by typing _______return_string("welcome")_______

Comment: @The_Inquisitive. VS code likely outputs the result of the last statement when you run a script

Answer (score 0):

Because "return string" returns a string, you must first save the data in a variable, which you may then use later in the program.

```
result_string = return_string("welcome")
print(result_string)
```

Comment: You don't need to save anything, you can just print directly

Comment: I believe that keeping a response as a variable will make it easier to use later. If we had just printed it, I would have to agree with you.

Comment: My point is that the explanation you give for why it doesn't print is totally unrelated to the actual reason